# DoubleSlider 4 autohotkey gui

Tags: user-interface, controls, autohotkey

After some research for DoubleSlider gui control for ahk, I wanted to ask for any solution. Soon later I have made a module on my own.

I am asking If there is maybe simpler solution? Much code was written to handle two sliders and prevent focus gaining. Anyway glitches are almost absent.

code:
https://snipplr.com/view/331639/doubleslider-4-autohotkey-gui/

[image]

package:
http://siwego.net/dev/doubleslider.zip